# JQueryMobile - Change pages with swipe

Tags: android, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, launcher

Does anyone knows if I can change pages by using swipe event and moving the page at the same time the finger is swiping? Thanks!

I've Googled it but I haven't found anything.

Comment: Have you tried just changing the page in the [swipe](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html) event?

Comment: @Jack yes but the problem it's that I want the pages to change at the same time as the finger. Like android swipe pages or iphone

Comment: jQuery Mobile `swipe` events don't work in "real-time." They wait for the touch-event to finish and then determine if it was a `swipe` or not. If you want 1-to-1 finger movement to page movement, then you're looking at a lot of custom code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There would be JQM 1.0b2 [pagination](http://filamentgroup.com/examples/jqm-pagination/demo/) (to be updated - see [here](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jqm-pagination-plugin))

The plugin changes pages as you swipe through them. Maybe a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just looking for the same thing.
Check this out: http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/